# Max flow with multiple distinct sources and sinks

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, max-flow

I'm trying to solve a max flow problem where I have multiple sources and sinks. I know that normally I could do this by adding a super-source and a super-sink, but in my problem I have an extra constraint. Each source is paired with a specific sink and must have flow going into that sink, but not into any other sink. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: What's the maximum number of sources and sinks?

Comment: 10 sources and sinks

Comment: If you use Edmonds-Karp, it seems like you just need to run the BFS 10 times to find the shortest augmenting path.

Comment: Is flow allowed to 'mix' in intermediate vertices? For example, what's the answer with sources '1, 2', paired to sinks '4, 5', respectively, with a middle node '3' and edges 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5. Or in other words, must paths be vertex and/or edge disjoint?

Comment: They have to be vertex and edge disjoint, so in that example the solution would either be 1 -> 3 -> 4 or 2 -> 3 -> 5.

Comment: I don't think that Edmonds-Karp with 10 BFS will work because when creating a new path from source to sink it may sever a previously built path.

Comment: You are correct that my suggestion won't work given that you have added the "disjoint" requirement.